# AttributeError: __enter__ ; context manager inside function

Tags: python, function, file-handling, attributeerror, contextmanager

```
def get_reply(file_name, input): 
    import csv
    #error line
    with open(file_name, "r") as csv_f, csv.reader(csv_f, delimiter = ",") as csv_reader:  
        return search(csv_reader, input)
```

Error :

```
in get_reply
     with open(file_name, "r") as csv_f, csv.reader(csv_f, delimiter = ",") as csv_reader:
   AttributeError: __enter__
```

**Why is this error occurring and how to resolve it? What does this error mean in this context?**

Thanks a lot for your help, I am fairly new to programming..

I will attach the rest of the code, for context, that is meant to process replies to user input by going over a csv file [user_input,response].

The code is written ***this way so that it can be imported and reused***.

```
def search(csv_reader, input) :
    for line in csv_reader:
        if input == line[0]:
            return line[1]

def get_reply(file_name, input): 
    import csv
    with open(file_name, "r") as csv_f, csv.reader(csv_f, delimiter = ",") as csv_reader:
        return search(csv_reader, input)

        
#Test execution                      
list1 = get_reply("csv_dataset.txt", input("Enter Input : "))
```

Comment: csv_reader is not a context manager, use it in the with statement

Comment: See also [how the with statement works](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`csv.reader` has not implemented the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods. So you cannot use it as context manager (this is what you do with the `with`).

Use it in this way:

```
def get_reply(file_name, input): 
    import csv
    with open(file_name, "r") as csv_f:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_f, delimiter = ",")
        return search(csv_reader, input)
```

---

If you want to use it as context-manager you can build own wrapper with the [contextlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html).

```
import csv
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def csv_reader(*args, **kwargs):
    yield csv.reader(*args, **kwargs)


with open(file_name, "r") as csv_f, csv_reader(csv_f, delimiter = ",") as reader:
    return search(reader, input)
```

Comment: There's no reason to make it a context manager, though: `csv.reader` just *uses* an open file object, and is not responsible for ensuring it gets closed. It also doesn't do anything that requires clean-up in the event of an except (as your definition makes evident: you don't do anything before or after yielding the `csv.reader` instance).